# Backend List Filter as simple dropdown

Tags: octobercms

I have to tables with a one-to-many relationship. Lets call them countries and citizens. In the backend I can filter the citizens by country:

```
# ===================================
# Filter Scope Definitions
# ===================================

scopes:

    country:
        label: Country
        modelClass: Acme\Blog\Models\Country
        conditions: country_id in (:filtered)
        nameFrom: name
```

Now I only want to select one country at a time. With this group filter, I always have to **deselect** the previously selected country, then **select** the one I want and press `Apply`.

Is there a way to get a simple DropDown with all the countries in it, where I can just click on a country and my citizen-list is filtered to that country?

Answer (score 0):

What you are requesting does not exist out of the box in OctoberCMS.

If you're looking for a simple solution- I would add a `text` filter and allow the user to filter by typing in a few letters of the country.

Comment: Thank you. I thought of that, but unfortunately it's not an option in my case.As I hinted at ("let's call them...") the actual dataset is a bit more complicated than countries and citizens.